# Where do I need to release the memory in iOS without ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have a method and don't use ARC:

```
-(void)readAppPlist
{
    NSString *plistPath = [self getDataFileDestinationPath];
    NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
    NSString *errorDesc = nil;
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSMutableDictionary *temp = (NSMutableDictionary *) [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
    if (!temp) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, formatL %d", errorDesc, format);
    }
    items = [[temp objectForKey:@"Items"] mutableCopy];
}
```

According to the rules of memory management where do I need to release the memory for the variables plistPath, plistXML, errorDesc, temp? Shall I writh another one method, release them here or just put them into the dealloc global method for this class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Assuming** you followed naming conventions correctly (and that is probably a pretty big leap), the answers would be:

plistPath : No
plistXML : No
errorDesc : No
temp : No

The rule is if you `alloc` `copy` or `retain` it, you must release it (`new` counts as `alloc`)

Comment: @borrden So, I don't need to do anything with the variables in this method in the whole application?

Comment: I'm not going to answer that (not because I want to be mean, but because I want you to truly understand the last line that I wrote).  Instead, look for places where you used any of the words I listed in the last line.  I see one occurrence, and that one will need to be released at a later time.